# Why my CSS-3 menu not showing sub-menu?

Tags: html, css

I am using [this vertical menu](http://www.thecodingguys.net/demo/css/css-vertical-menu.html).

When i add an image aside this menu, sub-menu did not show.

```
<nav id="menu"></nav><img src="1.jpg">
```

Check the screen capture below.

[image: menu]

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a minimal working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet.

Comment: Add More z-index to your #menu. like this : z-index:200;

Comment: Could you, please, add a snippet of your code with the styles you are using for the menu? It is really important which styles are you using

Comment: Without complete code, it's hard to get solution. So please replicate your issue here, using **Snippets**.

Comment: try to use bootstrap grid system for better solution

Answer (score 1):

Add More `z-index` to your `#menu`. like this :

```
#menu{
   z-index:200;
}
```

Comment: I have update your code in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8h6jkm8m/  .. this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The content gets into scroll.

I am guessing that, you are using `float` to get your menu to left and the image next to it. When you add float, the object loses it is flexibility on the entire page and becomes a block element.

Try this;

```
#menu {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}


 <h3>CSS3 Vertical Menu With Sub Menus</h3>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="parent-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home &amp; Kitchen</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cars &amp; Motorbikes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T&amp;C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div style="height:100px;width:200px;background:red;float: left;margin-left: -200px;"></div>
```

Comment: In this way your webpage not seems to responsive.. try to make responsive using grid system

Comment: I used bootstrap.put the menu with col-md-3 and the img with col-md-9

edit z-index :200

but its not show up

Answer (score 0):

try to use bootstrap grid system

Script Files..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Html Code

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">

               //put your menu code here...

             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">

              // put your image here...

             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```